# Shower niche tile unfinished edge?

Tags: shower, tile

[image: unfinishedtileedge]
[image: tileunfinished]

I hired a construction company to remodel my master bath, they just completed the job and upon first glance it looked great and I blessed the work. After they left and I looked more closely, they have left a raw edge on the tile around both shower niches that were installed. Not only does this look terrible (note the barcode showing on one edge), it won't be waterproof as that raw edge will absorb water unless sealed in some way. What do I do?? Fix it myself? Call them back to cut out and correct the problem? Call a tile expert to fix? I have not yet paid the balance on the job.

Comment: The barcode stood out to me, since you paid you can ask them to fix it. You may be able to scrub the barcode off, I can't tell how porris the tile is. If it is very porris schoch brite pads may take the code off but it probably should be sealed after that. Don't use scotch brite on glazed tile as it will scratch the surface.

Comment: The water seal isn't a problem as that's done behind the tile. Did they trim the tile job? That is to say, add something like [this](http://www.tileasy.com/product/metal-contract-tile-trim/)? Could be metal, could be plastic, it caps off open edges of tile.

Comment: No, no metal trim, just standard bullnose tile to finish the main edges. From other online images, I assumed they would install bullnose tile around the insert, like a picture frame...

Comment: @Celeste That's a proper assumption. Whatever the finished edges are like elsewhere it is to be assumed at that this niche should be finished the same way. You'll want to contact the contractor about this.

Answer (score 2):

That is not a professional job. Good thing you have not paid in full. That needs to be removed and redone properly with bull nose and polish the edges of the glass tile so they meet properly and not show such a wide grout joint to cover the edge of the rough cut glass tile. This is something THEY need to do. What I suggest is common practice that is done by professional tile setters. I hope they can do you justice.